No power in washroom exhaust fan receptacle
Washroom exhaust fan suddenly stopped working. I thought Fan is faulty. Removed the fan from enclosure and connected to power outlet, fan is working. Then checked the power in switch, I see the response on voltage tester with RED LED and beep. Then inside enclosure I tested the receptacle, I see no response on tester, I tested the wires going into receptacle, I saw the response (LED and Beep). Does this mean that only receptacle is faulty and needs replacement, or should I check other things? 


You've done a fairly good job troubleshooting your problem. You need to get a decent multimeter if you plan on doing more testing though.  The outlet appears to be your problem. They can get corroded due to the moist air going through the fan. The next step would be to disconnect the outlet from the power and test for continuity between the wires and the actual contacts in the outlet. At this point I'd be hooking up a light bulb to the switched feed to verify switched power to the outlet.  If the outlet proves defective, you can Google "exhaust fan outlet" or contact the fan manufacturer for a replacement part.
Just a safety precaution: always turn off the breaker whenever working on stuff like this. Do not just turn the switch off since the switch might be bad or someone might accidently turn the switch back on.

Or it switches neutral and leaves the hot, hot.
